# Why would Henry keep the teeth in his office where they could be easily found?

Tags: longmire

In S02E13 Fales finds Miller Beck's teeth in Henry's office.

In S03E01, Henry explains, "I wanted to make sure you never tried to take the fall for a murder you did not commit."

But in S02E13, Fales had very little evidence on either Walt Longmire or Henry. So Henry had little reason to let himself be arrested at this point.

So why would Henry not simply have kept the teeth somewhere else safer (e.g. just dig a hole anywhere in Wyoming and place the teeth there) than right in his office?

Comment: I haven't watched this. But could it be a referece to Edgar Allen Poe's short story *Berenice*?